# Wireless acting very slow

Tags: windows-7, windows, wireless-networking

I have a laptop running windows 7 but the wireless acts very slow for some reason. Sometimes I can't even get pages to run

I've tried:

- disabling firewall
- running ccleaned
- disk defrag
- system clean up
- ran AV and spyware scans
- router/network is fine

I've also random lost connectivity with the wireless router and once again only this laptop gets it.
I've also had pings from 162ms ~5000ms 
I've narrowed this down to that it is a local problem software wise on the laptop.

other ideas?

Comment: Is it slow for the local network or for Internet or both. If Interent, test it with something like [Speedtest](http://www.speedtest.net/). Try to PING an address and see if you are dropping packets PING -t to test for a period of time CTRL-C to end. Are there any apps like DropBox or torrents running? Is the signal strength satisfactory? Is this a new issue or has it always been an issue?

Comment: Do non-wireless connections also run slowly? If not, try unplugging/replugging your router (my Linksys occasionally slows down/stops WLAN traffic, which can be fixed by a reboot of the router)

Comment: It's not at all network related run over 10 computers on the network and they don't act up at all. I might have found problem. I disabled the VMWare connections and it seems to be working better but still not sure because they never were a problem before. I've also reinstalled drivers and will keep messing around with the wireless adapter settings.

Comment: Apparently, that was not it. Still lost

Comment: Can you get a hold of a Wireless USB device?  Try connecting through that (instead of through your Laptop's wifi) and see if there is any difference.  If there is, maybe your wifi card has malfunctioned and needs to be replaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First set yourself to a better channel using a [network monitor](http://www.metageek.net/products/inssider/)

Analyse provider's service with http://netalyzr.icsi.berkeley.edu/ (providers do bad things to cheat with speedtest.net, this one shows what exactly goes wrong)

Comment: Everything there is correct and thanks for the analyse website. Looks way better then speedtest.
I've decided this is all local on the laptop. Sometimes it connects works fine, then other times it just disconnects and at times when connected I'll get pings from 162ms ~ 5000ms

Comment: It could be bluetooth or microwave oven, not shown in wifi analyser in some channel.... You can try pinging your router, and then providers router from your router. You need to find the part of network that loses randomly...